# How to Check Image Exists in Public Folder of Next JS

Tags: typescript, next.js, file-exists, next.js13

I have a TypeScript Next.js project that has thousands of images in the public folder. Is there any way I can check an existing image before using the `<Image />` component in `next/image`?

I was able to do this using JavaScript only, but TypeScript is too complex. I also get an error returned from Next.js that says:

> The requested resource is not a valid image for `/cars/audi-4.jpg` received `text/html; charset=utf-8`

> ImageError: The requested resource is not a valid image.

How to check for existing `/cars/audi-4.jpg`? I would like to use a default image if it does not exist.

Comment: What kind of errors? Post the error message.

Comment: How you you get the filename in the first place?

Comment: I'm just type `<Image src="/cars/audi-4.jpg" ...` and that file indeed does not exists, I want to show another image if that file doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

**src\app\page.js (Next.js 13 app)**

Check the embedded comments for the flow

```
import Image from "next/image";

// Using HEAD method, just check the headers for status code
const isImageFound = async (imageName) => {
  return await fetch(`http://localhost:3000${imageName}`, {
    method: "HEAD",
  });
};

export default async function Home() {
  // default image name assignment
  let imageName = "/default.jpg";

  // this is the image we are looking for, not sure where you ar gonna pick this.
  let anyExistingImage = "/one.jpg";

  // Check the image is exists in public folder, if not take default image to render.
  const result = await isImageFound(anyExistingImage);
  if (result.status === 200) {
    imageName = anyExistingImage;
  }

  return <Image src={imageName} width={300} height={300} />;
}
```

**Folder structure with Public folder and page.js for Next.js 13 app,**

[image]

I hope this helps